# What app is this? Purple icon with a D and Unicorn

Tags: ios, applications

Wondering what app this is?

[image: iOS app icon Purple with a D and a Unicorn]

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Trivia questions (guess this app by description or screenshot) can work here, but some get down votes. If you are asking how to do an icon search or how to look up an app on a device you control, that generally gets lots of votes up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this iPhone app:

[Dreame - Read Best Romance](https://apps.apple.com/app/dreame-read-best-romance/id1421091911)

[image]